# htaccess redirect links from multiple subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Here's my dilemma now:

I have lots of links from multiple subdomains

`https://dev.example.com/abc.html`

`https://xyz.example.com/abc.html`

how can i redirect them using htaccess

`Redirect 301 https://dev.example.com/abc.html https://xyz.example.com/abc` **obviously doesn't work** sine it can only work with `/abc`.

And as i mentioned i have a lot of links there, and for some reason i would like to have it in htaccess

> Note that the **abc** is a valid page which exists on the destination url, therefore it will cause infinite loop if i use `/abc` because it will neglect the subdomain.
>
> The problem isn't redirecting from subdomain to another, that is not the case, the case is that i have links that i would like to redirect from subdomains to another, specific links.
>
> Therefore i'm not looking for something like nonwww to www kind of syntax.

#### I'm not looking to have something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

**Unless** it can be done with something like grouping all links under a certain subdomain `dev.example.com` then have all the links listed under it followed by the target url.

> That could be done with `php`, but i prefer to have it in `htaccess`.

The closest solution i believe it could work is to have those links scattered inside apache's vhosts

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName dev.example.com
  Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
  # Have the rest of links here
</VirtualHost>
```

Then

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName xyz.example.com
  Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
  # have the rest of the links here
</VirtualHost>
```

Valid?

## Update

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^tags\/xyz\.html\ $ "https\:\/\/dev\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^abcd$ "https\:\/\/dev\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

That's what i got in `htaccess` when i create the redirect from `cpanel`. so it validates what the solution i reached.

I'm close to finding the solution, now for ease of managing these, i'm looking for a way to group them all in one rule container.

Comment: @anubhava, it works, but that's not my point

Comment: there can be the same url on the other subdomain, so /abc will neglect the source subdomain, that will cause infinite redirects lets say `dev.x.com/abc` will redirect to `dev2.x.com/abc` ,what matters to htaccess now is /abc, and it exists

Comment: @anubhava i updated my question to clarify

Comment: The idea, is that my client had a site with single www.example.com now we want to separate content into subdomains, articles.example.com, faq.example.com ... and so on, the content still exists, we just want to redirect them properly, and there happens to be some custom 301 htaccess redirects there that should keep redirecting, that's why if i redirect /abc to faq.example.com/abc it will cause infinite redirects if i only use /abc as condition. i thought of apache vhosts, to have the links scattered within each vhost, if that's possible

Comment: @anubhava i have updated my question even more, i'm close to finding the solution, my only goal now is to group them under one container, if you may check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207121/discussion-between-anubhava-and-emad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VirtualHost` section is only allowed in Apache config or vhost config files and it requires `sudo` or `root` privileges to edit those files.

In absence of those privileges, it is always cleaner to have separate directory for each subdomain which allows a separate `.htaccess` per subdomain. This will allow you to keep all the rules for a subdomain in one `.htaccess`. This eliminates need to have `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` type condition before each rule.

---

For a single .htaccess, you may use this *alternate* approach where source is always `example.com` and target is a subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine On

# all other rules except redirect links to subdomains go here

# if current domain is not example.com then ignore all the rules below
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# all the redirects to subdomains go below

RewriteRule ^some-faq-item/?$ to https://faq.example.com/some-faq-item [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^from1/?$ to https://faq.example.com/to1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^abcd/?$ to https://dev.example.com/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: brilliant approach!